# Is it ok to use "spit" as past tense of "spit" or should I use "spat"?

Tags: spoken-english, lyrics

I was actually going through lyrics written by Eminem and there was a part where it was written

> Went to Burger King, they spit on my onion rings

So my question is since this is in simple past so shouldn't this be

> Went to Burger King, they spat on my onion rings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lyrics should not be treated as typical of normal prose due to "poetic licence". However "spit" is optionally used as a past tense in American English early modern English:

> And they spit upon him, and took the reed, and smote him on the head. (From the Bible, KJV Early Modern English Mat 27:30)

Standard British English would use:

> *I* went to Burger King; they *spat* on my onion rings.

Which would also be acceptable in American English.

Comment: In (Standard) AmE, *[spit](http://www.ldoceonline.com/license/amp/dictionary/spit)* can normally be used as the past simple form.

Comment: I checked and you're right.  Edited.

Comment: "Spit" in the past tense is more common in American English (I'd dare say it's the more common alternative), but it is common enough in British English to be listed as an alternative in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spit). You might want to edit your answer to more clearly reflect that these are both acceptable in both dialects, but that a different one is more common in each.